# Windows: how to call batch file with low priority with Ctrl+C support?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, command-line-arguments

I know that I can run a batch file with a low priority using command:

```
cmd /c start /B /BELOWNORMAL mvn.bat clean install && exit...
```

The problem is when I press Ctrl+C it does not stop the execution. Actually it allows me to type in the command prompt but the batch execution continues.

**Is it possible to run it with low priority and stop on Ctrl+C?**

Answer (score 1):

The command `START` starts `CMD` and not the opposite.

Remove `/B` to be able to use `Ctrl+C` also `/C` instead of `/K` will close the `CMD` when the script end.

```
start "" /I  /BELOWNORMAL /WAIT cmd /c "mvn.bat"
```

Type `HELP START` and `HELP CMD` for further reading.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to do so but not opening a new window?